# mp4parser AppendTrack Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, video, mp4parser

this is the error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox.getContentSize(ESDescriptorBox.java:60)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractBox.getSize(AbstractBox.java:203)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.getContainerSize(BasicContainer.java:70)
    at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.sampleentry.AudioSampleEntry.getSize(AudioSampleEntry.java:330)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.getContainerSize(BasicContainer.java:70)
    at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.SampleDescriptionBox.getSize(SampleDescriptionBox.java:112)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.AbstractContainerBox.getHeader(AbstractContainerBox.java:67)
    at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.SampleDescriptionBox.getBox(SampleDescriptionBox.java:94)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.mergeStsds(AppendTrack.java:81)
    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.AppendTrack.<init>(AppendTrack.java:65)
    at Mp4.merging.merge(merging.java:97)
```

and This My Code :

```
 if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
        }
```

And I cant find the Null Element .

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the vlc audio transcode , so the mp4 have a probleme with the sound track . 
i need to set audio encoding MP2L2 , but i dont khnow the correct VlC transcode options to make it work